# Variable not available in append in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

I'm doing a project where I have to add a email to a list. My code looks like this:

Html:

```
<ul class="auto-reports_recipients-list">
  <!-- List over recipients of the auto reports goes here -->
</ul>

<input type="email" placeholder="Enter email" class="auto-reports_recipient-email">
<button type="submit" class="auto-reports_recipient-email_button">+</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
if ($.inArray(email, recipientsEmailCollection) == -1) {
    recipientsEmailCollection.push(email);

    recipientsList.append('<li class="auto-reports_recipient">' + email);
    recipientsList.append('<button class="auto-reports_recipient-button" id="' + email + '>-</button></li>');

} else {
    // Output error message to tell that the input already is on the email list
    console.log(email + " already exists in array.");
}
```

Everything works fine (including line 4 in my JavaScript with the email variable value). However, when I want to append the email variable value to the button id on line 5 it breaks and tells me, that the email variable isn't defined.

Am I missing something?

Thanks!

Comment: How is `email` being defined? Also `id="' + email + '` is wrong, should be `id="' + email + '"`

Comment: *"...and tells me, that the email variable isn't defined...."* Please copy and paste the **exact** error into the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This snippet is not correct. There is no closing quotes and also unbalance tags.

You can use template literals using backtick

```
if ($.inArray(email, recipientsEmailCollection) == -1) {
  recipientsEmailCollection.push(email);
  console.log(email) // test t o check the email
  recipientsList.append(`<li class="auto-reports_recipient">${email}
                          <button class="auto-reports_recipient-button" id="${email}">-</button>
                          </li>`);

} else {
  console.log(email + " already exists in array.");
}
```